# Dataflow job is timing out. Having issues comparing two collections, and appending the values of one to another.

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Hoping someone can help me here. I have two bigquery tables that I read into 2 different p collections, p1 and p2. I essentially want to update product based on a type II transformation that keeps track of history (previous values in the nested column in product) and appends new values from dwsku.

1. The idea is to check every row in each collection. If there is a match based on some table values (between p1 and p2), then check product's nested data to see if it contains all values in p1 (based on it's sku number and brand). If it does not contain the most recent data from p2 then take a copy of the format of the current nested data in product, and fit the new data into it. Take this nested format and add it to the existing nested products in product.

   ```
   def process_changes(element, productdata):
       for data in productdata: 
           if element['sku_number'] == data['sku_number'] and element['brand'] == data['brand']:
               logging.info('Processing Product: ' + str(element['sku_number']) + ' brand:' + str(element['brand']))

               datatoappend = []
               for nestline in data['product']: 
                   logging.info('Nested Data: ' + nestline['product'])
                   if nestline['in_use'] == 'Y' and (nestline['sku_description'] != element['sku_description'] or nestline['department_id'] != element['department_id'] or nestline['department_description'] != element['department_description'] 
                       or nestline['class_id'] != element['class_id'] or nestline['class_description'] != element['class_description'] or nestline['sub_class_id'] != element['sub_class_id'] or nestline['sub_class_description'] != element['sub_class_description'] ):
                       logging.info('we found a sku we need to update')
                       logging.info('sku is ' + data['sku_number'])
                       newline = nestline.copy()
                       logging.info('most recent nested product element turned off...')
                       nestline['in_use'] = 'N'
                       nestline['expiration_date'] = "%s-%s-%s" % (curdate.year, curdate.month, curdate.day) # CURRENT DATE
                       logging.info(nestline)

                       logging.info('inserting most recent change in dwsku inside nest')
                       newline['sku_description'] = element['sku_description']
                       newline['department_id'] = element['department_id']
                       newline['department_description'] = element['department_description']
                       newline['class_id'] = element['class_id']
                       newline['class_description'] = element['class_description']
                       newline['sub_class_id'] = element['sub_class_id']
                       newline['sub_class_description'] = element['sub_class_description']
                       newline['in_use'] = 'Y'
                       newline['effective_date'] = "%s-%s-%s" % (curdate.year, curdate.month, curdate.day) # CURRENT DATE
                       newline['modified_date'] = "%s-%s-%s" % (curdate.year, curdate.month, curdate.day) # CURRENT DATE
                       newline['modified_time'] = "%s:%s:%s" % (curdate.hour, curdate.minute, curdate.second)
                       nestline['expiration_date'] = "9999-01-01"
                       datatoappend.append(newline)
                   else:
                       logging.info('Nothing changed for sku ' + str(data['sku_number']))
               for dt in datatoappend: 
                   logging.info('processed sku ' + str(element['sku_number']))
                   logging.info('adding the changes (if any)')
                   data['product'].append(dt)

               return data 

   changed_product = p1 | beam.FlatMap(process_changes, AsIter(p2))
   ```
2. Afterwards I want to add all values in p1 not in p2 in a nested format as seen in nestline.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm wondering why my job is taking hours to run with nothing to show. Even the output logs in dataflow UI don't show anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include a Dataflow job ID. Also: how big are "p1" and "p2"? It seems that, for every single element of the first table, you're scanning the entire second table. Is this intentional?

Comment: Dataflow Job ID: 2017-11-08_06_49_03-4712352492378635612

Comment: Yes I am scanning the entire second table because I need to be able to find the elements in p2 that are in p1 (then I need to check in the nested values in p2, to see if they match with p1). The sizes are for p1 and p2:  925mb, and 62.7mb respectively

Comment: Oh. That means your code is probably scanning many trillions of rows and discarding nearly all of them. Your use case doesn't seem to require this kind of nested looping because you're just joining data by a key. Chamikara's suggestion should work for you. I also recommend reading up about different types of joins in general, eg nested loops (aka cross join, Cartesian product), lookup joins, hash joins.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I will try what was recommended and touch back should I run into issues. Thanks again everyone! Super quick turnaround

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite expensive if side input PCollection p2 is large. From your code snippets it's not clear how PCollection p2 is constructed. But if it is, for example, a text file that is if size 62.7MB, processing it per element can be pretty expensive. Can you consider using CoGroupByKey: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey

Also note that from a FlatMap, you are supposed to return a iterator of elements from the processing method. Seems like you are returning a dictionary('data') which probably is incorrect.

Comment: Excuse me if this is a noob question. I am very unfamiliar with DataFlow but after looking into CoGroupByKey. How would I structure the code if I have p1 and p2 (pcollections) ? Looking at the docs, they don't show the code used to generate the results which is frustrating...

Comment: Also how does it know what key to sort by? Will it sort by every key? Is there a way to sort by 1 key specifically or a group of keys?